# Extract substring from a string using pattern

Tags: sql, regex, string, regex-group, presto

I would like to extract a substring from a lengthy string based on a pattern. Wondering what is the best way to get it?

```
http://abcdef?menu=xyz&source=push&push_id=1212239617294503480&message_id=7658a0a6-9d31-4c3c-9aa0-9169f24e2fdc
```

Pattern: `'menu'`

Substring looking for: `'xyz'`

Answer (score 5):

If your example accurately represents your end goal, the [`url_extract_parameter()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/url.html#url_extract_parameter) function is likely a better solution than regex:

```
SELECT url_extract_parameter('http://abcdef?menu=xyz&source=push', 'menu');
-- returns 'xyz'
```

Comment: +1  Parsing URLs is such a common task that it's best left to code that is specifically written to do it.

Comment: Agreed with @AndyLester that this is a better solution than regexes. Nice that Presto provides a built-in for that.

Comment: @DavidPhillips: it would be good if you could edit your answer to demonstrate how to actually use the function in OP's use case.

Answer (score 4):

In Presto DB, you should be able to use [function `regexp_extract()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html), in the form that supports capturing groups:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(val, 'menu=([^&]+)', 1)
```

Regex breakdown:

```
menu=        # litteral string 'menu='
(            # beginning of capturing group number 1
  [^&]+          # at least one character other than '&'
)            # end of capturing group number 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
menu=([^&]+)
```

You can check it [here](https://regex101.com/r/DdD67j/1)

Comment: How can I do this in SQL?

Comment: How can I do it in SQL?

Comment: You need to check if you SQL Db engine supports regex.